# Openfire Sql Database Integration

Tags: sql, sql-server, openfire

I'm following this guide (http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html) to integrate the Openfire server with and Sql Server Database.

I configured the openfire.xml like this:

```
<jdbcProvider>
<driver>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver>
<connectionString>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.21.40:1433/XmppTests;user=myusername;password=mypass;instance=sqlserver2008ex;</connectionString> 
</jdbcProvider>
<provider> 
  <auth> 
    <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider</className> 
  </auth>
</provider>
<jdbcAuthProvider> 
  <passwordSQL>SELECT password FROM dbo.Users WHERE username=?</passwordSQL>  
  <passwordType>plain</passwordType> 
</jdbcAuthProvider>
<admin>
    <authorizedUsernames>francisco</authorizedUsernames>
</admin>
```

When I turn the server on it doesn't show me any error, it reverts the file to the default values. I check the logs and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/38903).

> The setting(s) are stored in the DB with
>   3.6.4  I noticed this as well and only saw the DB reference in another
>   discussion and after checking my
>   install, yep, all in the DB except the
>   DB connection options.

And confirmation [here](http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/194594?tstart=0):

> Per an earlier thread, most of the SSO
>   config gets sucked into the DB at
>   startup, which is why you don't see it
>   in the XML file anymore.  This is
>   normal.

Comment: Yeah right, I eventually figured it out. It "sucks" the valid configuration into the DB. It should be mentioned in the guide. Thanks for links.

Comment: Seems pretty ridiculous - maybe a comment line at the top of the .ini file would work as well!

Comment: using GUI is the best option to integrate db